# TFS: database as datasource instead of Globallist.xml

Tags: tfs

TFS 2015.2.1. I have a custom field (combobox) that reads allowable values from Globallist.xml.
Can I use a database table as datasource instead of Globallist.xml files?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you want to do this?

Comment: Because if I have to add a value, using the database should I just insert a record (and I might let him do also to others users) while using Globallist should I personally update the file Globallist.xml, and this is a much more delicate operation.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

> A global list is a set of **LISTITEM** elements that is stored and
>   used globally by all team projects in a collection. Global lists are
>   useful for fields that are defined within several types of work items,
>   such as Operating System, Found in Build, and Fixed in Build.

This is by designed for using in a custom filed just like your situation. Global lists are pick lists that you can include in **one** or **more** fields and **types of work items.** Use them to **minimize the work** that is required to update a list that is **shared by multiple types of work items**. Using a database table can't achieve this feature.